# Zeros over zeta functions over finite fields

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

I'm reading about the zeta function over a finite field. The zeta function which is rational function $Z(t)=\frac{P(t)}{(1−t)(1−qt)}$, where $P(t)$ is polynom of degree $2g$ and $g$ is genus. I'm nteresting about their zeros. But reading about this topic I find books and papers that usually writing for  of points on a curve over a finite field. Is this the same or what?

Comment: More or less. The zeta function of a function field of a curve over a finite field can be viewed a generating function containing information about the number of points on (the smooth model of) the curve over all finite extensions of the base field. Could you possibly mention a particular zeta function you find interesting? I hazard a guess that the two users who voted to close this want to see some additional context or such. Another problem is that right now a comprehensive answer to your question could [fill an entire book](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387953359) :-)

Comment: The zeta function which is rational function $Z(t)=\frac{P(t)}{(1-t)(1-qt)}$, where $P(t)$ is polynom of degree $2g$ and $g$ is genus.

Comment: [This WP-article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_zeta-function) describes the basic connection between the zeta-functions and numbers of points. Does that help you at all?

Comment: I read it, but I still can't understand the differences of zeros with the points of curves.

Comment: Have you seen it applied to elliptic curves? Genus one is the simplest case where $P(t)$ has zeros (the projective line is a bit dull as $P(t)=1$ in that case). If $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{F}_q$, then the zeta-function leads to the Hasse-Davenport relations giving us a formula for the number of points on $E(\Bbb{F}_{q^n})$ in terms of the number of points on $E(\Bbb{F}_q)$ for all $n$.

Comment: Yes, but in that case zeta function has no zeros. So what I want to know is when the zeta function has zeros is it same as counting points.